# Enum case with associated value of generic type with constraints

Tags: swift, generics, enums

Is there a way, using generics and type constraints, to collapse the first two cases of this `enum` into one?

```
enum AllowedValueRange {

    // Associated value represents (min, max). 'nil' represents
    // "no limit" for that interval end (+/- infinity)
    case IntegerRange(Int?, Int?)


    // Associated value represents (min, max). 'nil' represents
    // "no limit" for that interval end (+/- infinity)
    case FloatRange(Float?, Float?)


    // A finite set of specific values of any type
    case ArbitrarySet([Any])

    // (...Other cases with different structure of associated values
    // or no associated values...)
}
```

**Addendum:**
I know I can specify a generic type for the whole `enum`, but only these two types need one. Also, I think it needs to conform to both `Equatable` and `Comparable`, but I can't quite find the syntax to specify that...

---

**EDIT:** It turns out `Comparable` contains `Equatable` (?), so perhaps I can do this:

```
enum AllowedValueRange {

    // Associated value represents (min, max). 'nil' represents
    // "no limit" for that interval end (+/- infinity)
    case NumericRange((min:Comparable?, max:Comparable?))

    // (rest omitted)
```

*(Also switched pair of associated values with single, named tuple of two values)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* define

```
enum AllowedValueRange {
    case NumericRange((min:Comparable?, max:Comparable?))
}
```

but that would allow you to instantiate a value with two
*unrelated* comparable types, for example

```
let range = AllowedValueRange.NumericRange((min: 12, max: "foo"))
```

which is probably not what you want. So you need a generic type
(which is restricted to be comparable):

```
enum AllowedValueRange<T: Comparable> {
    case NumericRange((min:T?, max:T?))
}
```

Comment: I see. The only thing that I don't like about this solution is that, I really don't need `T` in any of the other `case`s; I wish I could declare it only for `NumericRange` and not the whole `enum`.  I guess this is the best I can get.

Comment: That is, I wish it would be legal to declare: `enum AllowedValueRange { case NumericRange<T: Comparable>((min:T?, max:T?)) /* ... */ }`

Comment: @NicolasMiari: I see, but I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

###### Option 1:

You can a static function with the desired generics. For example:

```
static func numeric<N: Comparable>(range: (min: N?, max: N?)) -> AllowedValueRange {
    .numericRange(range)
}
```

You can also add `@available` to warn the caller about the direct usage and suggest an auto-fix:

```
@available(swift, deprecated: 1.0, renamed: "numeric(range:)")
case numericRange((min: Any?, max: Any?))
```

###### Note:

It may be weird for this use-case but it may make more sense for different situations like passing `ViewBuilder`s to `AnyView` cases ‍♂️

---

###### Option 2:

You can also wrap `allowed` types inside another enum (as a namespace) and use it like:

```
enum ValueRange {

    static func numeric<N: Numeric>(range: (min: N?, max: N?)) -> AllowedValueRange {
        switch range {
        case let (min, max) as (Int?, Int?): return .IntegerRange(min, max)
        case let (min, max) as (Float?, Float?): return .FloatRange(min, max)
        default: fatalError("Unknown type")

        }
    }
}
```

so the caller will see only 1 method and that takes generic `Numeric`s:
[image: Usage]

###### Note:

The `<<error type>>` Will go and will be detected by the compiler as soon as you pass in the parameters.

---

##### Conclusion:

Each of these methods (including another answer by @Martin R) has its own cons and pros and you should pick the one which is right for your needs